# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/saved_model_cli'

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Environment**:

- TensorFlow: 2.0
- Ubuntu: 16.04

The main thing I wanna do is to uninstall TensorFlow2.0, and install TensorFlow1.12...
I wanna uninstall TensorFlow2.0 using command like : `python3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow` , but I encountered some errors like below:

```
Uninstalling tensorflow-2.0.0:
  Would remove:
    /usr/local/bin/saved_model_cli
    /usr/local/bin/tensorboard
    /usr/local/bin/tf_upgrade_v2
    /usr/local/bin/tflite_convert
    /usr/local/bin/toco
    /usr/local/bin/toco_from_protos
    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow-2.0.0.dist-info/*
    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/*
    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/*
Proceed (y/n)? Your response ('') was not one of the expected responses: y, n
Proceed (y/n)? Your response ('') was not one of the expected responses: y, n
Proceed (y/n)? Your response ('') was not one of the expected responses: y, n
Proceed (y/n)? Your response ('') was not one of the expected responses: y, n
Proceed (y/n)? Your response ('') was not one of the expected responses: y, n
Proceed (y/n)? Your response ('') was not one of the expected responses: y, n
Proceed (y/n)? Your response ('') was not one of the expected responses: y, n
Proceed (y/n)? Your response ('') was not one of the expected responses: y, n
...
Proceed (y/n)? Your response ('') was not one of the expected responses: y, n
Proceed (y/n)? Your response ('') was not one of the expected responses: y, n
Proceed (y/n)? Your response ('') was not one of the expected responses: y, n
Proceed (y/n)? y
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 538, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/saved_model_cli' -> '/tmp/pip-uninstall-slo6qv86/saved_model_cli'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 79, in run
    auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 755, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 394, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 283, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 338, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 553, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/saved_model_cli'
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try though, Try the same command with sudo.

`sudo python3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow`